# Python TCP & UDP proxy/relay

Tags: python, linux, sockets

OS: CentOS
Python: 2.4 and 2.7

I'm trying to build a relay or proxy for both TCP and UDP traffic for my applications.
My setup is app1 verifies app2 is online by constantly sending UDP packets.
Once app1 verifies that app2 is online, it will then send app2 data packets via TCP protocol.

This is my code so far:

```
#-------------------------------------
#SOCK_DGRAM --UDP
u_localPort = 20006
u_remotePort = 20006
u_remoteHost = "x.x.x.x"

u_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
u_sock.bind(('', u_localPort))
u_knownClient = None
u_knownServer = (u_remoteHost, u_remotePort)
#-------------------------------------

#-------------------------------------
#SOCK_STREAM --TCP
t_localPort = 10006
t_remotePort = 10006
t_remoteHost = "x.x.x.x"

#client
c_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c_tcp.connect((t_remoteHost, t_remotePort))

#server
s_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s_tcp.bind(('', u_localPort))
s_tcp.listen(1)

conn, addr = s_tcp.accept()
#-------------------------------------

while True:
    u_data, u_addr = u_sock.recvfrom(4096)
    if u_knownClient is None:
        u_knownClient = u_addr
    if u_addr == u_knownClient:
        u_sock.sendto(u_data, u_knownServer)
    else:
        u_sock.sendto(u_data, u_knownClient)


    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data
    c_tcp.send(data)  # echo
```

With this code the UDP data seems to be relaying properly. But the TCP isn't.
What could be wrong?

Comment: Why probe with UDP before sending via TCP?  Why not just use TCP from the beginning, and assume no connection means not available?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere where you make any socket [non-blocking](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking).  So any call to recv or recvfrom will hang until data is actually received.

So when you get into the main loop, you block forever on the call to `usock.recvfrom(4096)`.  Until you actually receive a UDP packet, your code won't make it to `conn.recv(1024)` line.

Consider using non-blocking sockets (with proper [select/poll](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) semantics).

Comment: Sorry I'm new. How do you do that? I checked select.

Comment: ala `u_sock.setblocking(0)`  and `c_tcp.setblocking(0)`